# How is $\{ (1/n , 1 + 1/n) \}_{n \geq 1}$ a cover for $(0,2)$?

Tags: general-topology

Can someone tell me why $\{ (1/n , 1 + 1/n) \}_{n \geq 1}$ could be a cover for $(0,2)$? (I know it is not compact)

I don't see how the point $0 \in \bigcup_{n\geq1} (1/n, 1 + 1/n)$

Comment: Do you know the fact that $0\notin (0,2)$?

Comment: Yes, I do know that

Comment: Then, what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking about (and drawing) $[0,2]$ for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ isn't in the union, but then $0 \not\in (0, 2)$.

Comment: Then how can $(0,2) \in$ the union then?

Comment: Careful, $\in$ means an element of. $(0, 2) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n}, 1 + \frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: *$\subset$ was what I meant sorry

Comment: If $(0, 2) \not\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n})$, there is $x \in (0, 2)$ with $x \not\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n})$. Can you show this can't happen?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking about $[0,2]$ for some reason.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

The point $0$ is not in $(0,2)$, so the fact that it is not in $\bigcup_{n\geq1} (1/n, 1 + 1/n)$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $I_n=(\frac1n,1+\frac1n)$.
Let $x\in(0,2)$. If $x>1$ then $x\in I_1$.
If $x\le 1$, then there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n>\frac1x$ and hence $x\in I_n$.
Therefore $(0,2)\subseteq \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} I_n$. (In fact, $(0,2)= \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} I_n$).